# Sum of 2 irrational numbers, rational or irrational, more?

Tags: irrational-numbers

How can I prove that the sum of two irrational numbers is most likely irrational number?

Comment: Let's focus on the first question: *is more irratinal or rational numbers[?]*  The best I can make out of this is "are there more irrational numbers than rational numbers?", but I don't see how it is connected to the first sentence. Can you clarify please?

Comment: I think what OP is asking is if we pick two arbitrary irrational numbers, what is more likely, the sum being rational or irrational?

Comment: ok, for example a, b, c are irrational numbers and d is rational number. I know that a+b=c or a+b=d. And the question is: When i do the sum of two irrational numbers - the result of the sum is mostly irrational number or is it mostly rational number. And I'm sorry for my english, I don't come from english speaking country.

Comment: If you fix one irrational $\alpha$ then there are uncountably many irrationals $\beta$ such that $\alpha + \beta$ is irrational and only countably many $\gamma$ such that $\alpha + \gamma \in \mathbb Q$.  Is that the sort of thing you are after?

Comment: Yes, Anurag A, that is what I wanna know.

Comment: How to define "more likely" when each option corresponds to infinitely many choices?

Comment: Yes, lulu, but I need to prove it somehow, my teacher is strict. I don't know how to prove it. His tasks are crazy. I think it's almost impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a fixed number $z$, you can take each $q\in \mathbb Q$ and find the unique $y_q\in \mathbb R$ such that $z+y_q=q$. Since each $y_q$ is unique, clearly there are only countably many numbers with that can be found.

So out of the entire pool of $|\mathbb R|$ things that can go into the $y$ of "$z+y$", only countably many will yield a rational number, and the rest (uncountably many) will yield an irrational number.

Comment: But z and y have to be irrational, not rational. Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: @Lucie I don't understand what problem you are describing in your last comment. $z$ can be an irrational number, everything still applies. There are still only countably many $y_q$ all of which are *necessarily irrational*.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbb{S}$ denote the set $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$, then:

- $\forall{x\in\mathbb{S}}:x+(1-x)\in\mathbb{Q}$
- $\forall{x\in\mathbb{S}}:x+(x-1)\not\in\mathbb{Q}$

Therefore, since $\mathbb{S}$ is uncountable:

- The amount of rational results is uncountable
- The amount of irrational results is uncountable

Comment: How can rational results be uncountable?

Comment: @orion: There are (uncountably) many results for each rational value.

Comment: @orion: For example: $1=\sqrt2+(1-\sqrt2)=\pi+(1-\pi)=\phi+(1-\phi)=e+(1-e)=\dots$.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but what is more likely, the sum being rational or irrational? and how would you prove it?

Comment: @Lucie: I think that since there is an uncountable amount of **different ways** to generate each one of them, the probabilities are identical. But I think that it generally requires proving $|\mathbb{R}|=|\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}|$, and I'm not really sure how to prove this one (or even whether or not it is true to begin with).